2D transformation matrix how to revert or dismiss scaling?
I'm working on a web application which uses fabric.js to make drawings on the web page's canvas.
I will tell you about some general properties of this tool for context:

Canvas is a space that has its own cartesian coordinate system with reverted $y-axis$ meaning the valeus of $y$ increase as we go towards bottom.
Each object created in canvas such as rectangle, text etc. has their own $3\times3$ transformation matrix that tells the position/translation of the object's center. This transformation matrix tells us where the object is relative to the center of the canvas space.
We can use each object's transformation matrix to calculate where other objects are located relative to that object. To calculate where object $B$ is located relative to object $A$, we can do the below calculation:

$$T_{A}*X=T_{B}$$
$$T^{\prime}_{A}*T_{A}*X=T^{\prime}_{A}*T_{B}$$
$$X=T^{\prime}_{A}*T_{B}$$
Here, $X$ is the unknown transform matrix that tells where the object $B$ is at relative to object $A$, it also defines a relationship between these objects. $T_A$ is object $A$'s transformation matrix and $T_B$ is object $B$'s transformation matrix. Prime notation is used to notate that it's inverse matrix.

Now, I will scale the object $A$ in $x-axis$ by 2, doubling its width. This will cause T_A to change, we can calculate object $B$'s new transform matrix using the relationship transform matrix we found in the previous step.
$$T_{B}=T_{A}*X$$

When I apply the newly found $T_B$ transformation matrix to the object $B$ it successfully shifts the center of the object $B$ twice as before since we have scaled object $A$ in $x-axis$ by factor of $2$. Object $B$'s previous translation in $x-axis$ was $-61.98$ and it's now $-123.97$ (roughly doubled). In this process, the relationship matrix $X$ was unchanged and used to calculate new transform matrix of object $B$. Everything is good so far!
Now, what I'm having trouble is avoiding object $B$ from being also scaled or reverting the scaling applied to object it. As you can see, in the first picture text was smaller but when the object $A$ got scaled by $2$ in second picture, it also got scaled. This causes text to be drawn disrupted. I want the text to look as same as it looked in first picture but preserving its relative position to the parent object which is object $A$. It should remain right below the bottom left corner of rectangle. The scale applied to transformation matrix of object $B$ seem to be also causing its translation properties in $x$ and $y$-axes to be scaled in some way. Because when I revert the scaling of object $B$ programmatically by setting the text's scale property back to its original value which is $1$, text appears slightly off in the direction of the scale applied. Below is the picture where I revert the scaling applied to object $B$ programmatically:

I need a way to prevent object $B$ from scaling somehow multiplying the $T_B$ we have found with some kind of transform matrix that will revert the effect of scaling applied on it's translation values in $x$ and $y-$axes. But I couldn't figure out what kind of transform matrix ı should be using.
NOTE: When we rotate the object, rotation matrix also gets into action in the calculations. Please think throughly in a case where we also rotated the parent object $A$.

SMH how can software developers make their geometry problems sound so complicated :P (Disclosure, I'm also a software developer now.) Let's try to chip away at this and get to whatever the real problem is.

Each object created in canvas such as rectangle, text etc. has their own  $3\times 3$ matrix I suppose this means you're using affine transformations to place things, then.

We can use each object's transformation matrix to calculate where other objects are located relative to that object. I have no idea what that could mean...

Depending on people's monitor dimness, I wouldn't be surprised if they missed that black "child text" completely in your screenshot.

@rschwieb thanks for assisting! I tried to be as clear as water in explaining the problem but I think I made it worser by putting a lot of detail. Anyway, you are correct in your assumptions with affine transformations. In fabric.js each object has their own transformation matrix and each object declares a new plane or coordinate system that takes their center as the origin. When we want to know where another object is located relative to that object, we can use that object's transformation matrix as shown in the calculations.

Do I understand correctly that you want the B transform to go to the correct position within the x-scaled A frame, but you don't want the text in the B object frame to experience the x-scaling?

@rschwieb you understood my issue correctly!

@rschwieb oh yeah thanks, I just updated the post.

Let $D=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\0&1&0\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Does $(DT_A)^{-1}T_BD^{-1}$ do what you want?

Which object should I apply this transform to? (Also we can carry this conversation over a chat room, if that's ok for you.)

@rschwieb I applied your proposal's resulting transform matrix to children object $B$ and I assumed that $D_{11}$ is scale-x applied to parent. It caused child object to shrink each time I rescaled the parent object in $x-axis$ causing it to disappearedd at some point.

$(DT_A)^{-1}T_BD^{-1}$ is a replacement for your earlier attempt $(DT_A)^{-1}(DT_B)=T_A^{-1}T_B$.  The idea is that it pre-shrinks $B$ so that the unwanted stretch is counteracted in the end.  Not completely sure it's what you're headed for though. And yes, move it to chat if you can.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
